# TypeScript instanceof guard fails

Tags: typescript

This line of code seems straightforward:

`const dates: Date[] = [1, new Date()].filter(num => num instanceof Date)`

However, it fails with the error:

`Type '(number|Date)[]' is not assignable to type 'Date[]'`

Why can't TypeScript infer that the only items that would be in dates are from the Date class?

Comment: Because `1` is not a date.

Comment: You can add `as Date` to avoid it.

Comment: How is it straightforward? `filter` does **not** alter the return type. `map` does that instead, you are **filtering** the original array that is a `(number|Date)[]`, hence, since it's **filtered** the result will be a `(number|Date)[]`. There is nothing wrong with typescript in that case. If you are explicitly sure that the result will be a date[], just cast it: `as Date[]`. Keep in mind that you're working with **types** on a **typeless** language. At runtime, all of this will **not** exist.

Comment: I think it's straightforward in that the return value of the filter statement here is 100% compatible with Date[], and in fact no other type statement beyond any[] would work. But I see what you mean @briosheje, after this statement I could do a dates.push(2), and so had TypeScript inferred my type than it would have gotten it wrong. I'll explicitly add a type assertion.

Comment: @Breck The type assertion here is **mandatory** because typescript is a transpiler and, because it **transpiles** code, it doesn't look at the code **values** and is not aware what type will the array be at runtime. In your case, **you** are telling typescript that such array specifically is a `Date` array because, originally, it has a mixed type. I do understand your point, but you should still think that **at runtime** all those checks will be useless, because types just does not exist in javascript, so a manual assertion here is, sadly, needed. Interesting example, anyway!

Comment: @briosheje I agree with your points except that TypeScript's instance of guards are evaluated at compile time and not runtime, see the Padder instanceof guard example: (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript can't quite infer this correctly, unfortunately, but if you use a type predicate in your filter function it works:

```
const dates: Date[] = [1, new Date()].filter((num): num is Date => num instanceof Date)
```